# search engines and robot file

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

i have a word-press site and don't want google to crawl in the documents in a specific folder of my media.
i have created a robot.txt file which disallowed that path but i just found out that google indexed all the info in those documents. what else can i do??
thank you

hello ,
i have a word-press site and don't want google to crawl in the documents in a specific folder of my media.
i have created a robot.txt file which disallowed that path but i just found out that google indexed all the info in those documents. what else can i do??
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using add it on robots.txt :

```
Disallow: /first_url/*
Disallow: /second_url/*
```